# Forward button for cordova uwp windows 10 app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, uwp, windows-10

I can see back button for cordova based uwp windows 10 app on top left. Since its kind of web app, I need forward button as well like browser to navigate between the url history.

Is that possible? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need forward button as well like browser to navigate between the url history.
>
> Is that possible? Please suggest.

In UWP there is no pre-defined forward button, as a workaround, you can create a RuntimeComponent and set the `CoreApplicationViewTitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar` to true to "hide" the default title bar just like the [official title bar demo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/TitleBar/js) did. then add your custom title bar(a div element add to the top of `body`) and define the back/forward button in your custom title bar.

Comment: Do you mean, we should have our own custom title bar designed in our HTML file with what ever buttons we need with appropriate actions?